# How to let android studio align assignment when reformating the code?

Tags: android-studio, coding-style, alignment, reformat

Let's assume we have this code:

```
int x;
double yyyy;
float zzzzzzzz;

x = 1;
yyyy = 24.5d;
zzzzzzzz = 1.3f;
```

after I enabled:
Settings -> Code Style-> Java -> Wrapping and Braces -> Align Variable in columns
and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> it It is reformatted to the following:

```
int    x;
double yyyy;
float  zzzzzzzz;

x = 1;
yyyy = 24.5d;
zzzzzzzz = 1.3f;
```

Is there any way to make the result like this:

```
int    x;
double yyyy;
float  zzzzzzzz;

x        = 1;
yyyy     = 24.5d;
zzzzzzzz = 1.3f;
```

with equal indents when assignment multi variables like last three lines.

Answer (score 0):

No way to align the code like that. After five years, there is no way still.